# difference between checkpoint and docker export

Tags: docker, export, containers

What is the difference between checkpoint and docker export? I know that docker export result in a .tar containing the filesystem of the container. What about checkpoint?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Checkpoint? According to the [tag you used](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/checkpoint/info) you're referring to a firewall vendor. Could you be more specific?

Comment: sorry, I mean checkpoint/restore in CRIU(https://criu.org/Main_Page)

Answer (score 4):

Checkpoint/Restore allows to dump the state of all the processes (memory, file descriptors, sockets etc) to the filesystem, so that a running container can be resumed on the same host or a different one (therefore allowing live migration or a running container).
Docker export is just about the file system state, and does not allow live migration of containers.
The checpkoint/restore feature is available ([albeit in experimental state](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md)) in docker 1.13.